# ASP.MVC и dialog

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

По нажатию на ячейку таблицы создается диалог для отображения данных и возвращается как частичное представление. При нажатии на кнопку next необходимо закрыть текущий диалог, послать запрос в контроллер, который вернет новый диалог и отобразить его.

Код первого диалога:

```
var dialog = document.querySelector('dialog');  
if (!dialog.showModal) {  
    dialogPolyfill.registerDialog(dialog);  
}  
dialog.showModal()  
dialog.querySelector('.close').addEventListener('click', function () {  
    dialog.close();  
})  
dialog.querySelector('.next').addEventListener('click', function () {  
    $.ajax({  
        url: '/Home/OneEvent',  
        type: 'Post',  
        success: function (res) {  
            dialog.close();  
            $('.OneEvent_container').html(res);  
            $('.OneDay_container').html();  
            dialog.close();  
        }  
    })  
})
```

При нажатии на кнопку контроллер возвращает также частичное представление с новым диалогом, но он не отображается.

```
var dialog = document.querySelector('.dialog2');
if (!dialog.showModal) {
    dialogPolyfill.registerDialog(dialog);
}
dialog.showModal()
dialog.querySelector('.close').addEventListener('click', function () {
    dialog.close();
})
```

Класс dialog2 добавлен во второй диалог, по отладке вижу, что переменная dialog заполняется верно, но диалоговое окно не отображается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все оказалось просто, в `javascript` коде содержатся строки

```
$('.OneEvent_container').html(res);  
$('.OneDay_container').html();
```

В `OneEvent_container` результат возвращаемый `ajax` запросом записывается верно, но в следующей строке не происходит стирание предыдущего диалога. Получается на странице 2 элемента dialog и программе не понятно какой из них отображать. Исправляется заменой на:

```
$('.OneEvent_container').html(res);
('.OneDay_container').html('');
```